# How do I correct html4 4.01 in asp.net using vs2012

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

In vs 2012 asp.net empty site I am using html4.01 for table desgin 
I have a `<div>` (a couple actually) and i keep getting a warning that reads:

```
    </div>
    <div style="text-align:center;">
       <table style="text-align:left; border-color:aqua;background-color:gold;border-width:2px;"cellspacing ="0" cellpadding ="8" rules ="none" width ="540">
        <tr>
            <td valign ="top">
                Me
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```

```
Warning 1   Validation (HTML 4.01): Element 'tr' cannot be nested within element 'div'.
```

what would cause this?

Comment: What part of the message don't you understand?

Comment: well, look at the line pointed in your validation report, and the error message is quite self-explanatory : you probably have a `tr` somewhere which is not within a `table` element...

Comment: your /table is misplaced. You should close your table after the /tr

Comment: see my question , <tr> is under <div> tag, so can i know whats the problem?

Comment: Your `<table>` tag is probably broken by the missing space between the style and cellspacing attributes.

Comment: Is the markup in the question really an extract from the document that caused the warning message? It does not trigger any error message or warning from W3C Markup Validator when using HTML 4.01 Transitional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code you've posted:

You have a table, and the nesting *looks* like you intended to put the `<tr>` inside it.

However, the table is closed on the same line as it is started, so the `<tr>` is actually outside the table, after it.

Find the closing `</table>` tag, and move it to where it should be, after the rest of the code that is meant to be inside the table.

**[EDIT]**
Okay, you've now fixed that in the code in the question.

The next problem I can see is that your table tag has the following:

```
border-width:2px;"cellspacing ="0"
                ^^^
          missing space here
```

The missing space before the `cellspacing` attribute will cause the tag to be invalid, which could also be breaking it.

For further HTML validation, I recommend you put your HTML code through the [W3C's validator](http://validator.w3.org/), which will highlight any further issues you may have with your HTML.

Comment: okay, well, that should solve the problem. (I see you've edited the code in the question to do that; did it work?).

Comment: It is impossible to see what the problem was, since the edit history does not show a prematurely closed `table` element.

Comment: A space is not required between attribute specifications according to HTML 4.01 and in browser practice. It is required in HTML5, but the code does not conform to HTML5 in general (it uses obsolete attributes).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - it's a pity the edit history lost the changes. (in fact, it's a pity he edited it out at all; it rather destroys the usefulness of the question). It was there at the time with the `</table>` tagged onto the end of the `<table>` line. I'm fairly sure that was the actual problem. The additional point I made in the edit was me trying to find anything else wrong with it, because he didn't acknowledge my "did it work?" comment until a bit later.